# Html 5 upload file , ajax , jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I am trying to upload file via jquery, so what I want to do is using the ajax POST method and post the uploaded file to `url:"/files/uploads"` with the parameter `file` ,so I have this input

```
<form id="fileUploadForm">
    <label class="btn-bs-file btnAddFile btn btn-lg btn-primary">
          <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
              <span>Add New File</span>
                  <input type="file" id="fileInputUpload" />
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
     </label>
</form>
```

and this is how i try to post into server

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {

        //stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get form
        var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

        // Create an FormData object
        var file = new FormData(form);
        // If you want to add an extra field for the FormData
        file.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data, testing");

        // disabled the submit button
        $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", true);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/files/uploads",
            data: {file:file},
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 600000,
            success: function (data) {


            },
            error: function (e) {


            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @jhpratt this is my error {"file":["The file field is required."]} and this is request payload [object Object]

Comment: Error from _where_? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: @jhpratt error from server , so this is my response from server

Comment: Have you tried printing out variables along the way? What kind of debugging have you done?

Comment: @jhpratt I want a better solution only, can you help me with better solution than this, how to achieve this, can you refer me somewhere else

Comment: I'm asking what kind of debugging you've done to solve the problem. Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service.

Comment: @jhpratt i debug i get this error, ReferenceError:data is not defined

Comment: @jhpratt i evaluated the ajax request and i get this error Uncaught ReferenceError: file is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
data: {file:file},
```

it should be:

```
data: file,
```

Also, you need to give a name to the file input, it should be:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="fileInputUpload">
```

Comment: it is still the same problem

Comment: I get this error when i evaulated ajax Uncaught ReferenceError: file is not defined

Comment: I don't see how you could get that error, when you have the line `var file = new FormData(form);`

Comment: That is what I asked the question, neither i dont understand why

Comment: If you weren't getting that error with `data: {file: file},` then you can't get it with `data: file,`. You must have changed something else as well.

Comment: Maybe i am using wrong method, can you suggest me better solution for uploading files with parameter file

Comment: There are many questions here about uploading files with AJAX. You're doing it correctly if you make my fix.

Comment: I made your fix but server responses that file parameter is missing,

Comment: Your `<input type="file">` is missing `name="file"`.

Comment: Barmar thank  you, post this answer here so i can mark it as correct